# Which API key do I use in SpeechRecognition (Google) in python

Tags: python, api

I am working on a project that uses voice recognition in python and I was looking at some example code, I was wondering which API key to use and what does it look like.

```
def callback(recognizer, audio):
# received audio data, now we'll recognize it using Google Speech Recognition
try:
    # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
    print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio)) <-- right there
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    pass
except sr.RequestError as e:
    pass
```

I have a google developer account. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create an account here [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/). You will be able to get a limited amount of api requests with a free account.
for a full documentation, visit https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/rest-tutorial